# How to avoid run time error while working with dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a piece of code that represent Dictionary and search key array.

```
Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                   {
                                     {"1","Blue"},
                                     {"2","Green"},
                                     {"3","White"}
                                    };

string[] keys = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

How to safely avoid the run time error when i pass a key that is not present in dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to safely avoid the run time error when i pass a key that is not present in dictionary?

You haven't shown how you're *currently* trying to do it, but you can use [`Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx):

```
foreach (string candidate in keys)
{
    string value;
    if (items.TryGetValue(candidate, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key {0} had value {1}", candidate, value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No value for key {0}", candidate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either `ContainsKey`  or `TryGetValue` to check the existence of a key.

```
string val = string.Empty;
 foreach (var ky in keys)
 {

                if (items.TryGetValue(ky, out val))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }

     }
```

or

```
foreach (var ky in keys)
 {

   if (items.ContainsKey(ky))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(items[ky]);
    }
  }
```

Though TryGetValue is faster than ContainsKey use it when you want to pull the value from dictionary.if you want to check the existence of key use ContainsKey.

Comment: Why would you use `TryGetValue` and then *also* use the indexer? That's pointless - at that point you've already got the value in `val` (which doesn't need to be definitely assigned when you call the method, by the way).